# eclipse is not detecting unstaged changes

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

we used eclipse ide for php in combination with a gitlab server to develope and stage our php application for more than a year now without any problem. Recently eclipse is not detecting any unstaged changes. After uninstalling eclipse and reinstalling it, the staging worked fine for a few commits.  After a short time period i had the same weired behaviour again. The other people in our team with the same configuration have no problems at all.

pulling form the repo works fine, also in case of a merge conflict when pulling i get the expected notification.
also the compare window works as it should. The problem seems to be only in detecting unstaged changes. The .gitignore file is inconspicuous.

The error log shows the msg: Error occurred computing Git commit diffs

windows 10, eclipse ide for php developers, Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0), Build id: 20210612-2011

Comment: In case you also using the command line Git (or in some cases when changing files outside of Eclipse), you have to do a _Refresh_ (F5) in the _Git Staging_ view. When there is something in the log, show the log starting with `!SESSION`. Your question is weird in the way that you tell Eclipse is doing something rather than what you did using Eclipse. Maybe you did _Assume Unchanged_ or missed to look into the `.gitignore` files of the parent folders as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Refreshing the staging view was not helping. I recently removed the repo and cloned it from the server again. After that it worked fine for 2 commits. Now eclipse is not detecting unstaged changes again. I also checked all .gitignore files and setted all files to 'No Assume Unchanged' with no success.

Comment: That does not answer what I asked for. Which file did you change how (inside or outside of Eclipse? white-space or non-white-space changes?)? Is it a project file? If yes, how is it displayed in the _Project Explorer_ and how in the _Git Staging_ view? Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'd recommend pinning this down to whether it's purely Eclipse, or a more general problem: once it starts happening, see if command-line Git behaves well. If so, you know the problem is in Eclipse itself. If not, you know it's something outside Eclipse.

Comment: @torek How likely is it that such a general problem is in Eclipse (or EGit?) itself and has remained unnoticed by so many until now?

Comment: @howlger: More likely that it's a general problem in Git that has remained unnoticed by so many until now. :-) (Git is amazingly widely used.) In any case that's just part of a binary search: if it's general to both, it might be an OS thing.

Comment: @torek Both Git implementations, git-core and JGit/EGit are amazingly widely used and both have had their last release several weeks ago.

Comment: first thanks for the fast help and sorry for the inconvenience. I startet to try out the workflow with a new repo and only one file. This seemed okay. Gradually I added some more files also with no problems. Finally I copied all files of the old repo in a new one. It seems to work now. However this does not solve the problem of the old one...